# Firebase (Android): image not being displayed on my listView, once I first upload it to Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, image, firebase-storage

I'm implementing an instant message app in Android (FriendlyChat, part of the Firebase Udacity course, by the way).

It saves and displays either a written message, or an image, per message. The class for these saved items is called FriendlyMessage, which contains the message's author, and then text or an image.

I've set the ChildEventListener within onAuthStateChanged, which is coded on onCreate. This being said, the AuthListener is only called on onResume (attaching/adding it to the DatabaseReference), and on onPause (detaching/removing).

The Send button's onClickListener is also set within onCreate. The text in the EditText is passed to a String, the FriendlyMessage instance is created, and then saved to the database with the .push().setValue(object) method.

Whenever I do this, the onChildAdded is called, where I can add the most recent FriendlyMessage instance to the adapter, and the written message is displayed in the ListView.

With images, I've got a button that opens my image files, and then I select one, then being called onto onActivityResult.

Here, I'm able to retrieve the image, store it in FirebaseStorage, and even save it to the database (also with push().setValue(object) method).

**However**, and with the help of some logs I've coded, I notice that the **onChildAdded isn't being called**, and therefore, also because the app has probably been paused in the meantime, my ListView remains blank (the ListView is cleared upon onPause). When I rotate the phone, or when I restart the app, all the content appears, including the image uploaded. But of course, as you know, it's important that the image is shown right away, upon being uploaded by the user.

What am I doing wrong? Or what can I do so that the onChildAdded is called when the image FriendlyMessage instance is saved onto the database (knowing that right now this is being called on onActivityResult) ?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    public static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;

    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;
    private TextView mDisplayNameTextView;

    private String mUsername;

    private int countChildEventCalls; //for testing ChildEventListener calls

    //Firebase variables
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageReference;

    private List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> mAuthProviders = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        countChildEventCalls = 0;

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
        mChatPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("chat_photos");

        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        mDisplayNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_name);

        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
        List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });

        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);

                mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);

                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
              }
        });

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if(user != null) { //the user is logged in
                    onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName());
                }

                else { //the user isn't logged in yet. Gotta launch FirebaseAuthUI
                    onSignedOutCleanup();
                    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                        .setAvailableProviders(mAuthProviders)
                        .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
                return true;

            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(mAuthListener != null) {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
        mMessageAdapter.clear();
    }

    public void onSignedInInitialize(String displayName){
        mUsername = displayName;
        mDisplayNameTextView.setText(mUsername);

        if(mChildEventListener == null){
            attachDatabaseReadListener();
        }
    }

    public void attachDatabaseReadListener(){
        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                countChildEventCalls++;
                Log.v(TAG, "Could be Text or Photos: calling ChildEventListener");
                FriendlyMessage message = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
                mMessageAdapter.add(message);
                Log.v(TAG, "Text or Photos: message added to Adapter. Calls: " + countChildEventCalls);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Text or Photos: calling onChildChange!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Text or Photos: onCancelled called.");
            }
        };

        mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }

    public void onSignedOutCleanup(){
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        mMessageAdapter.clear();
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    public void detachDatabaseReadListener(){
        if(mChildEventListener != null){
            mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.v(TAG, "Photos: Started activitiyForResult");
        Log.v(TAG, "for Photos purpose, requestCode = " + requestCode + ", resultCode = " + resultCode);

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You're logged in! Type with your friends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign-in cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            uploadImageToChat(data);
        }

    }

    public void uploadImageToChat(Intent dataIntent){
        Log.v(TAG, "Photos: Reached photo picker RC request");
        Uri imageUri = dataIntent.getData();
        final StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = photoRef.putFile(imageUri);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String stringUrl = uri.toString();
                        Log.v(TAG, "Photos, uploaded, path: " + stringUrl);

                        FriendlyMessage imageMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, stringUrl);
                        mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(imageMessage);
                        Log.v(TAG, "Photos: Added Message to database");
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        //mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        /*
            Task<Uri> taskUri = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return photoRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Photos: upload successful");
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        String stringUrl = task.toString();
                        FriendlyMessage imageMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, stringUrl);
                    } else {
                        // Handle failures
                        // ...
                        Log.v(TAG, "Photos: wasn't able to upload photo");
                    }
                }
            }); */


    }

}
```

MessageAdapter.java:

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendlyMessage> {
    public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FriendlyMessage> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        FriendlyMessage message = getItem(position);

        boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;
        if (isPhoto) {
            messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                    .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                    .into(photoImageView);
        } else {
            messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
        }
        authorTextView.setText(message.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, in the meantime.

On my onSignedInInitialize method, I had stated that if the ChildEventListener was null, only then I would add my ChildEventListener to the Database Reference. Being that I was removing this listener on onPause, and that it probably wasn't null as I was returning to the mainActivity (on onActivityResult), I believe I wasn't attaching the event listener to the database reference, hence nothing being displayed after the image being uploaded.

So I removed the mentioned condition, and added the ChildEventListener instance to the database reference as soon as I was back on onResume. It worked.

Thank you, still!
Best regards,

Comment: Feel free to tell me what best practices are there, though. Much appreciated ;)